# C++ local scopes to reduce memory?

Tags: c++

When trying to reduce memory use as much as possible, I have seen some programs use additional local scopes. Is this the best way to reduce footprint? Will the variables be removed from the stack when the brackets close? Would it be better to explicitly `delete` the objects, or is this equally good? Or would the compiler simply remove extraneous brackets?

```
void foo()
{
    {
        int a = 4;
        BigObject obj1;
        obj1.operations(a);
    }
    {
        double b = 9;
        BigObject obj2;
        obj2.operations(b);
    }
}
```

Comment: First call of **operations** should be **obj1.operations(a)**, isn't it?

Comment: You're leaking your `BigObject`s. If you hadn't `new`ed them, then yes, the compiler would've called their destructors at the end of their respective scopes, which usually means those objects deallocate whatever memory they'd grabbed on to.

Comment: You are leaking memory. The scopes only take care of the automatic storage objects (i.e. the `int` and `double`.)

Comment: @dhganey There is no any sense in your code example and moreover it will not be compiled.

Comment: Remember: Prefer automatic objects over dynamic allocation where possible. Also, C++ does not have garbage-collection, so prefer allocating directly into a smart-pointer, using `new` if neccessary but prefering `make_unique`, `make_shared` and the like.

Comment: @Gluttton: if at all `obj1->`

Comment: The code does not make any sense and almost 30 minutes later the OP has not clarified. The question should be closed until the question is clarified.

Comment: Sorry guys, my original code was pretty careless. Thanks all for contributing!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes, they introduce new scopes.** Objects with *automatic storage duration*, i.e. objects on the stack ("local variables"), will go out of scope at the end of this scope.

You are guaranteed that destructors are called, but you are not guaranteed that the object is actually removed from the stack (since *stack* is an implementation detail -- the standard only talks about automatic storage duration).

However, there is rarely a performance reason for doing so. Instead, it can be useful when using the [RAII pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAII).

Note, however, that **this only applies to local variables**. Dynamically allocated memory, i.e. objects on the heap (that you allocate with `new`), will *not* be released until you explicitly `delete` them.

Dynamically allocated memory will have to be pointed to by pointers. C++ clearly separates the concepts of `pointer to BigObject` and `BigObject`. In other words, your program is ill-formed. You should write:

```
BigObject* obj1 = new BigObject();
//       ^-- Important!
```

You can not `delete` variables with automatic storage, so that part of your question does not make sense.

Not that instead of using `new`, you should generally prefer using `std::unique_ptr` instead:

```
std::unique_ptr<BigObject> obj1 = make_unique<BigObject>();
```

The memory allocated for your `BigObject` will be automatically released when `obj1` goes out of scope -- this is the RAII pattern.

Comment: Prefer `std::unique_ptr`, or some value-pointer, to `std::shared_ptr`.  `shared_ptr` should only be a last-resort.

Comment: @MooingDuck: You're right, old (and bad) habit. I changed it. Thanks!

Comment: end of scope resp. start of scope does not mean the memory will be freed / reserved: It is oftern more efficient to reserve once at function start and free it all at exit. (Space reserved != Objects valid / Access defined)

Comment: Is removing from the stack at the end of a scope guaranteed (C++ has no notion o a stack)?

Comment: @DieterLücking: I doubt it, since the standard only talks about automatic storage duration. However, you are guaranteed that destructors will be called, for example.

Comment: Preference list: Automatic > Static > dynamic using `make_unique` > dynamic+`unique_ptr` > dynamic using `make_shared` > dynamic+`shared_ptr`: Use the least dynanmic / flexible means which will get the job done, so you have the least fuss and the highest efficiency.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Yeah, I just realized that my wording was clumsy, and updated it. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I have pondered this in the past, but the reality is it does not actually save space according to my nasty experiment. The locals appear to still stock consecutively on the stack:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int* nasty = NULL;

    {
        int value = 1;
        std::cout << &value << std::endl;
    }

    {
        int value2 = 2;
        std::cout << &value2 << std::endl;
    }

    {
        int value3 = 3;
        std::cout << &value3 << std::endl;
        nasty = &value3;
    }

    std::cout << nasty[0] << ", " << nasty[3] << ", " << nasty[6] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
001FFC38
001FFC2C
001FFC20
3, 2, 1
```

Comment: Seems like undefined behavior (and horrible way to code).

Comment: Oh it absolutely is UB. Proves in the case of MSVC that a sequence of locals created and terminated in blocks, does not result in stack space being reused for each variable. In case anyone is in question: PLZ don't use this code. There is a reason I named the pointer "nasty".

Comment: What compiler optimization setting did you use?

Comment: Ah, had done this experiment before but was in debug (default), so no optimizations. In Release mode I do see address reuse. Ill probably delete this answer then as this is now incorrect, it depends on optimization settings. Cheers cmaster, learned something.

Comment: @Chris: Your test is correct, but only tests objects with automatic duration.  If you add a large `std::string` in each block, you'll see that the c local scopes do reduce memory.

Comment: This experiment is incomplete. Since you're only adding a few ints, the optimizer could have made a judgement call to simply leave the data on the stack since it amounts to nothing. A more complicated example might yield different results.